# string or binary data would be truncated - but don't know parameter values

Tags: sql-server

The company program prints out the `string or binary data would be truncated` error to an error table when trying to insert into a specific table. I do realize from other posts that the cause of this is the current table structure. There are one or more fields that are too short, but unfortunately I do not have access to the values of the actual query. Instead, it dumps them as `@parametername1, @parametername2,` etc. from the stacktrace.

Is there any way I can see from some kind of monitoring tool in SQL Server 2012 what parameter and value failed? I mean, the SQL Server has returned the error, so supposedly I can log it if I repeat the error?

Comment: Can't you alter what ever code is responsible for logging the error to also log the parameter values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a trace in SQL Profiler.  For the statement, it will give you list of columns and matching values being inserted.